# How should the JSON be for storing values like below

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to store Json values to array below.

If only single event,

```
private static final String[] Eventname = {"Wedding"}
private static final String[][] Bid= {{"Studio 1"}}
private static final String[][] location= {{"Ernakulam"}}
```

If multiple events and multiple bidders,

```
private static final String[]  Eventname = {"Wedding","Funeral"};
private static final String[][] Bid={{"Studio 1","Studio 2","Studio 3"},
                {"Studio 1","Studio 2","Studio 3"}}; 
private static final String[][] location= {{"Ernakulam"},{"Kollam"}}
```

I have created a json for eg:

```
[
  {
    "Event": "Wedding",
    "Studios": [
      "Studio 1","Studio 2"
    ],
    "Location": ["Ernakulam","Bangalore"]
  },
  {
    "Event": "Birthday",
    "Studios": [
      "Studio 1"
    ],
    "Location": ["Ernakulam"]

  },
  {
    "Event": "Engagement",
    "Studios": [
       "Studio 1","Studio 2","Studio 2"
    ],
    "Location": ["Ernakulam","Bangalore","Angamaly"]
  }
]
```

But how can i get this json values and store it in above arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple json parsing libraries in java.
You could for instance use javax.json.

In that case you could do

```
try(JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(yourJsonString))){
 JsonArray arr = jsonReader.readArray();
 ... run through the entries in arr here and fill your arrays accordingly ...
}
```

But I should note that the structure you're trying to create makes no sense and is very non-java-like.  I would recommend you to create appropriate classes to represent Event, Venue and Bidding.  It will make your life way easier in the end...

Answer (score 1):

**Try This As You Need**

```
public class Test {

private static final String[]  EventName = new String[50];
private static final String[][] Bid = new String[50][50];
private static final String[][] location= new String[50][50];

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        String sampleJSON = "[\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"Event\": \"Wedding\",\n" +
            "    \"Studios\": [\n" +
            "      \"Studio 1\",\"Studio 2\"\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"EventObject\": [\"Ernakulam\",\"Bangalore\"]\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"Event\": \"Birthday\",\n" +
            "    \"Studios\": [\n" +
            "      \"Studio 1\"\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"EventObject\": [\"Ernakulam\"]\n" +
            "\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"Event\": \"Engagement\",\n" +
            "    \"Studios\": [\n" +
            "       \"Studio 1\",\"Studio 2\",\"Studio 2\"\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"EventObject\": [\"Ernakulam\",\"Bangalore\",\"Angamaly\"]\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "]";


    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ArrayList<EventObject> eventObjectArrayList = gson.fromJson(sampleJSON, new TypeToken<List<EventObject>>(){}.getType());

    for (int i = 0; i < eventObjectArrayList.size(); i++) {

        EventName[i] = eventObjectArrayList.get(i).getEvent();

        for (int j = 0; j < eventObjectArrayList.get(i).getStudios().size(); j++) {
            Bid[i][j] = eventObjectArrayList.get(i).getStudios().get(j);
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < eventObjectArrayList.get(i).getLocation().size(); k++) {
            location[i][k] = eventObjectArrayList.get(i).getLocation().get(k);
        }

    }
}
}
```

> You Need GSON jar com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 import it into your project or add jar as lib in your project.
>
> This is your EventObject class

```
public class EventObject implements Serializable {

String Event;
ArrayList<String> Studios;
ArrayList<String> Location;

public EventObject() {
}

public String getEvent() {
    return Event;
}

public void setEvent(String event) {
    Event = event;
}

public ArrayList<String> getStudios() {
    return Studios;
}

public void setStudios(ArrayList<String> studios) {
    Studios = studios;
}

public ArrayList<String> getLocation() {
    return Location;
}

public void setLocation(ArrayList<String> location) {
    Location = location;


 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) you can write own deserializer for your JSON and read it as you wish:

```
public static class Events {
    private final String[] event;
    private final String[][] bid;
    private final String[][] location;

    public Events(String[] event, String[][] bid, String[][] location) {
        this.event = event;
        this.bid = bid;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String[] getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public String[][] getBid() {
        return bid;
    }

    public String[][] getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}

private class EventsDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Events> {
    protected EventsDeserializer() {
        super(Events.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Events deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ArrayNode arrayNode = p.readValueAsTree();

        String[] events = new String[arrayNode.size()];
        String[][] bid = new String[arrayNode.size()][0];
        String[][] location = new String[arrayNode.size()][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
            JsonNode internalNode = arrayNode.get(i);
            events[i] = internalNode.get("Event").asText();
            bid[i] = convertToArray(internalNode.get("Studios"));
            location[i] = convertToArray(internalNode.get("Location"));
        }

        return new Events(events, bid, location);
    }

    private String[] convertToArray(JsonNode childNode) {
        String[] locations = new String[0];
        if (childNode != null && childNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode locationNodeArrayNode = (ArrayNode) childNode;
            locations = new String[locationNodeArrayNode.size()];
            for (int j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {
                locations[j] = locationNodeArrayNode.get(j).asText();
            }
        }
        return locations;
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule();
    sm.addDeserializer(Events.class, new EventsDeserializer());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(sm);

    Events events = mapper.readValue(JSON, Events.class);
    System.out.println(events);
}
```

But I would recommend you make your internal structure closer to original Json:

```
  public static class Event {
    @JsonProperty("Event")
    private String event;
    @JsonProperty("Studios")
    private List<String> bid;
    @JsonProperty("Location")
    private List<String> location;

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public List<String> getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(List<String> location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Event[] jsonEvent = mapper.readValue(JSON, Event[].class);
    System.out.println(events);
}
```

As you can see Jackson able to make all work for you if you provide the proper mapping. It would help you to get more clear code, have separate instances for every node  and don't mix all objects in one array, which looks like bad design.